# BIML to create multiple projects in a single solution

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2015, biml, ssis-projects

Can you use BIML to create multiple projects within a single solution?

The following creates a single project with two packages within it, but I'm trying to create two separate projects with a package in each:

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Projects>
        <PackageProject Name="ProjectOne" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey">
            <Packages>
                <Package PackageName="PackageProjectOne" />
            </Packages>
        </PackageProject>
        <PackageProject Name="ProjectTwo" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey">
            <Packages>
                <Package PackageName="PackageProjectTwo" />
            </Packages>
        </PackageProject>
    </Projects>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="PackageProjectOne" Language="None" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey" />
        <Package Name="PackageProjectTwo" Language="None" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey" />
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

What I'm trying to achieve (two distinct projects, with a package in each):

[image: TwoProjects]

Presumably because the BIML files reside within each project, you would need to start with two projects, then build the BIML from each project - is that right?

What if I wanted to use a single solution to build only one project, or two / three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, the Biml file drives the current project, in a Visual Studio context at least. Crossing projects doesn't "really" work like you're hoping.

This is the result of running the supplied Biml in Visual Studio via BimlExpress

[image]

And that makes sense, to me at least. There are a few restrictions in the BimlExpress product, one is that it doesn't emit project parameters and it *seems* it also ignores the Project setting in general

What if we step up to the paid for solution, BimlStudio? Here I have the same BimlFile1.biml

[image]

After executing the script, it generates the 4 artifacts under the Integration Services node: 2 projects, 2 files. The next step is to Build to a project and that's where what you're looking for falls down. You can only build one project at a time. You can multiselect projects but it only builds the last one selected.

[image]

Build will then create a Solution and project but it you'd have to manually add the project from one to the other.